# Badminton dataset

Tags: sports

I am looking for Badminton data set. Olympics record or badminton world federation record will be good or any data related to badminton sport should be fine. If anybody have or can provide , it will be great help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few that I found on web :

- [Open Gym](https://data.townofcary.org/explore/dataset/open-gym/export/?disjunctive.facility_title&disjunctive.pass_type&disjunctive.community_center&disjunctive.open_gym&disjunctive.group&refine.pass_type=Open%20Gym%20-%20Badminton) dataset for badminton - check for other sports, if you're interested, may be you can find similar problem to solve
- [Gym Dataset,](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?tags=badminton) contains badminton data also
- [Images of Badminton](http://kahlan.eps.surrey.ac.uk/acasva/Downloads.html) - ACASVA dataset contains images
- [Stanford Images](http://vision.stanford.edu/lijiali/event_dataset/)  : contains some 200 images of badminton
- [Other Sports](https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Sports/datasets)